# Get publish or build date in Expo

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm looking for a simple way to see the date of build in the Expo app, especially for developer builds.

Is there a way to read the publish or build date using an Expo API?

If not, is there a simple way to include the build date in the build? For example, a script that changes some part of `app.json`.

Answer (score 5):

I managed to do this using the `extra` property in the Expo config, see this [expo guide](https://docs.expo.io/guides/environment-variables/#using-app-manifest--extra).

I added the file `app.config.js` that dynamically modifies the Expo config:

```
export default ({
  config
}) => {
  config.extra = {
    'buildDate': new Date().toISOString().replace('T', ' ').substring(0, 19) + ' UTC'
  };
  return config;
};
```

And then you can use the `buildDate` in your app:

```
import Constants from 'expo-constants';
console.log(Constants.manifest.extra.buildDate);
```